# Undefined variable error for already defined variable

Tags: javascript, html, logic

Variable `bodydata` is already declared in function `myfunction.This` variable is then passed to another function `createPDFTable` but in `createPDFTable` function....it is giving an error as :

> "uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".......AT line 129

Variable `bodydata` which is being passed to function `createPDFTable` is treated as undefined.Why and how to rectify this?

Fiddle link is -> https://jsfiddle.net/o8L3p0kk/

Comment: Indentation is atrocious. Please update your code so that it is readable.

Comment: Still bad. I can't tell where most blocks end.

Comment: please use some ide/sublime for identifying indentations please

Comment: I shouldn't have to. And, FYI, don't expect help here with that attitude.

Comment: really sorry ...i didn't imply that ...i tried to indent the code but since few of my lines are quite big...code moves to next line...really sorry

Comment: In that case, provide a jsfiddle link ;) (with good indentation)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o8L3p0kk/   this is the fiddle link....please have a look